# Android Studio - sync failed: Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir'

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to get the code from a friend's git, but the Gradle syncing fails even if I download and install all the dependencies required.

> Gradle sync failed: Cause: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir(Ljava/io/File;)

I get this error also:

> Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Comment: yeah have you checked internet connection?

Comment: @Eminem:   yup...unfortunately I don't think that's the problem

Comment: File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run.